# Make a signal wait until falling edge

Tags: matrix, signals, vhdl

I have this signal that should be zero until another signal Start = 0. How can I accomplish this? Here is the relevant code:

```
        din<=0;
        wait until falling_edge(start);

    for i in 0 to 63 loop
        wait until clk = '1' and clk'event;
        if i = 0 then
            Start <= '1','0' after clk_period;
        end if;
            if (i < 24) then 
                din <= 255;
            elsif (i > 40) then
                din <= 255;
            else
                din <= 0;
            end if;

        end loop;

    wait;
```

I thought I could just make din = 0 until the falling edge of start but it stops at the rising edge of start. I want to start reading the din values when start =0. Before that din = 0.

Here is a pic:
[image]

EDIT: Actually I got it to start at the correct signal values but the dout value always has an intermediate value that isn't necessary. In this case its 78450. I know this has to do with the testbench code but I can't get it to just calculate the correct value at the correct time. What changes can be made to the code below to get rid of the intermediate value?

[image]

```
            din<=0;


    for i in 0 to 63 loop
        wait until clk = '1' and clk'event;
        if i = 0 then
            Start <= '1','0' after clk_period;
            elsif (i < 24) then 
                din <= 255;
            elsif (i > 40) then
                din <= 255;
            else
                din <= 0;
        end if;

        end loop;
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all I assume (and hope) you are writing a testbench. If not, you should avoid using wait statements, as these have very limited support in synthesis tools.

Even in a testbench, it is best to use time-based wait or after statements only to generate the clock, and make all other signals dependent on an event (e.g. `rising_edge(clk)`). This avoids the problem of having multiple signals changing during delta cycle 0 along with the clock.

Consider the following code for a typical register:

```
process(clk) begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        a <= b;
    end if;
end process;
```

and assume that `clk` and `b` are generated in a testbench as follows:

```
clk <= not clock after 1 ns;

process begin
    b <= '1', '0' after 10 ns;
    wait;
end process;
```

- At time 0 delta 0, `clk` changes to '1' and `b` would change to '1'.
- At time 0 delta 1, the register process would run since `clk` changed, and `a` would change to '1'.
- No further sensitivity exists, so time would update to the next event at 1 ns.
- At time 1 delta 0, `clk` changes to '0'.
- At time 1 delta 1, the register process is run since `clk` changed, but nothing happens because `rising_edge(clk)` is false.
- The above repeats for time 2-9 ns.
- At time 10 delta 0, `clk` changes to '1' and `b` changes to '0'. Note that `clk` and `b` change in the same delta cycle.
- At time 10 delta 1, the register process runs and `a` changes to '0'! As far as the result is concerned, this means that `b` changed before the rising clock edge!

Even if this behavior is understandable in this simple system, it can lead to some incredibly difficult to find simulation bugs. It is therefore better to base all signals off of the appropriate clock.

```
process begin
    -- Initialize b to 1.
    b <= '1';
    -- Wait for 5 cycles.
    for i in 1 to 5 loop
        wait for rising_edge(clk);
    end loop;
    -- Set b to 0.
    b <= '0';

    -- Done.
    wait;
end process;
```

This avoids unexpected behavior, since all signals will change at least one delta cycle after the associated clock, meaning causality is maintained throughout all of your processes.

Answer (score 0):

`I have this signal that should be zero until another signal Start = 0. How can I accomplish this?`

Maybe you can use a handshake signal and put it in the sensitive list of the process. It will behave like a reset signal.

```
process (handshake_s, ...)
begin
  if (handshake_s = '1') then  -- failing edge of start
    din <= 0;
  else
    -- do something
  end if;
end process;
```

Use another process to update *handshake_s*.

```
process (start, ...)
begin
  if failing_edge(start) then
    handshake_s <= '1', '0' after 10 ns;  -- produce a pulse
  end if;
  -- do something
end process;
```

Would you mind post all your code here so that we could understand the waveform better?

Answer (score 0):

Testbench or RTL code?

**For a testbench**, your coding style is mostly ok, however, your signal Start has a problem and will never be '1' during a rising edge of clock.  It goes to '1' just after the rising edge of clock and will return to '0' either simultaneously with clock or 1 delta cycle before clock (depending on your clock setup).  Either way, anything running on rising_edge clock, such as your design, will not see it as a '1'.

A simple way to avoid this is to use nominal delays (25% of tperiod_Clk) on all of your testbench outputs that go to the DUT (Device Under Test).  The pattern for a pulse is as follows.

```
wait until clk = '1' ;  -- I recommend using rising_edge(Clk) for readability
Start <= '1' after tpd, '0' after tpd + tperiod_clk ;
```

Alternately, you can avoid this issue by not using waveform assignments.  Such as the following.  In this case, you don't need the tpd, however, if it really is a testbench, I recommend using it.

```
wait until clk = '1' ;  
if i = 0 then 
  Start <= '1' after tpd ; 
else 
  Start <= '0' after tpd ; 
end if ;
```

**For** RTL code, you need to explore a different approach.  Very briefly one way to approach it is as follows.  Note do not use any delays, waveform assignments, or loops.

```
-- Counter to count from 0 to 63.  Use  "+ 1".  Use "mod 64" if using type integer.
-- Start logic = decoder (can be coded separately) 
-- Din Logic = decoder (can be coded separately)
```